# Choosing choice function (for axciom of choice) bbased on well-orderred set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I saw one lecture stating that a well-ordered set implies Axiom of choice. Lecturer stated that let $E$ be a well-ordered set in a collection $S$ of non-empty sets. Then we can define function, $f:S \rightarrow \bigcup S$ as follows:
$$f(E) = \text{each minimum point in set $E$}, $$
then clearly $f(E) \in E$. Hence, a well ordered set implies Axiom of choice.

I though of example,

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be a set of all natural numbers, and $S = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, and define $E_1 = \{1\}, E_2= \{2,4\}, E_3 = \{1,2,4\}$. Define $f:S \rightarrow \bigcup S$ to be $$f(E_i) = \text{each minimum point in set $E_i$}\;\text{where} \; i = \{1,2,3\}$$
Then, $f(E_2) =2$ which implies $f(2)=f(4) = 2$. And $f(E_3) = 1$ which implies $f(1) = f(2) = f(4) =1$. Since by definition of function, one input(?) cannot be assigned to multiple outputs(?).

I am really confused now, can anyone solve please?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your example you don't have $S=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ but $S=\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ and $\bigcup S=\{1,2,4\}$.

Then $f$ is just the function defined over $S=\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ such that $f(E_1)=\min E_1=1$, $f(E_2)=\min E_2=2$ and $f(E_3)=\min E_3=1$.

But $f(1), f(2)$ and $f(3)$ don't exist because $1$, $2$ and $3$ are not elements of $S$, they are elements of $\bigcup S$.

So there is no problem with the definition of a function here, you have $f(E_1)=f(E_3)$ but that's fine, we never said that the choice function should be one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is not defined for individual natural numbers, its defined on $S$, the set of *subsets* of $\mathbf N$. It just does not make sense to write $f(1)$, $f$ is a function $\mathcal P(\mathbf N) \to \mathbf N$, not $\mathbf N \to \mathbf N$. You have $f(\{2,4\}) = 2$, and on one hand, this does not tell you anything about $f(\{2\})$ (which is $2$) and $f(\{4\})$ (which is $4$), on the other hand to write $f(2)$ does not make sense, as $2$ is not an element of $f$'s domain, which is $\mathcal P(\mathbf N)$.